# How do I remove items from the reader panel in safari

Tags: safari, macos

[image]

NO, all REMOVE button does is to turn a dropdown OFF.

I want to remove all them.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer was already on [Keep a Reading List in Safari on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/safari/keep-a-reading-list-sfri35905/mac), on Apple Support. You could have searched more. This is what it tells:

> Remove a webpage from your Reading List: Control-click the webpage summary in the sidebar, then choose Remove Item.
> You can also swipe left over the webpage summary, then click Remove. Or, swipe all the way to the left until the webpage summary disappears.

**This is to do on the Safari app, not in System Preferences.**

This is only to take them out one by one. *But you can shift-click to select a range and then control-click to delete them all.*

Comment: I have removed everything from the reading list, but the settings still show all items on the reader list.